# kNN feature should passed through as list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, knn

my data is like:

```
sample1 = [[1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 9], 0, 1.5, 0]
sample2 = [[0, 4, 0, 6, 2, 0], 2, 1.9, 1]
sample3 = [[9, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0], 0, 1.3, 1] 
paul = pd.DataFrame(data = [sample1, sample2, sample3], columns=`['list','cat','metr','target'])`
```

on this data a scikit-learn kNN-Regression with an specific distance function should be done.

The  distance function is:

```
def my_distance(X,Y,**kwargs):
    if len(X)>1:
        x = X
        y = Y
        all_minima = []
        for k in range(len(x)):
            one_minimum = min(x[k],y[k])
            all_minima.append(one_minimum)
            
        sum_all_minima=sum(all_minima)
        distance = (sum(x)+sum(y)-sum_all_minima) * kwargs["Para_list"]
      
    elif  X.dtype=='int64':
        x = X
        y = Y
        if x == y and x != -1:
            distance = 0
        elif x == -1 or y == -1 or x is None or y is None:
            distance = kwargs["Para_minus1"] * 1
        else:
            distance = kwargs["Para_nominal"] * 1
    else:
        x = X
        y = Y
        if x == y:
            distance = 0
        elif x == -1 or y == -1 or x is None or y is None:
            distance = kwargs["Para_minus1"] * 1
        else:
            distance = abs(x-y) * kwargs["Para_metrisch"]
    return distance
```

And should be implemented as valid distance function by

```
DistanceMetric.get_metric('pyfunc',func=my_distance)
```

As I'm right, the scikit code should be like this:

```
train , test = train_test_split(paul, test_size = 0.3)

#x_train soll nur unabhähgige Variablen enthalten, andere kommen raus:
x_train = train.drop('target', axis=1)
y_train = train['target']

x_test = test.drop('target', axis = 1)
y_test = test['target']

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2,
                          algorithm='ball_tree',
                          metric=my_distance,
                          metric_params={"Para_list": 2,
                                         "Para_minus1": 3,
                                         "Para_metrisch": 2,
                                         "Para_nominal": 4}))
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred=knn.predict(x_test)
```

I get

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I guess scikit can not handle a single feature item as list? Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: Is there a way to hide the information of a list in any accepted data type and unpack this list information in `my_distance` later in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess scikit can not handle a single feature item as list? Is there a way to make that happen?

No, there is no way I know of to make this happen. You need to convert this feature into 2D matrix, concatenate it with other 1D features, to form data appropriately. This is standard `sklearn` behavior.

Unless you have some very narrow use-case, making 2D array from list feature is totally fine. I assume, all lists have same length.

Comment: Thank You, thats what I thought. Is there a way to hide the information of a list in any accepted data type and unpack this list information in `my_distance` later in the process?

Comment: @paule Not really, one of the first things sklearn does is verifies that X is np.array-convertable.